# Why doesn't Git set the file time?

Tags: git, time, files

Git by default does not set the [file-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_time) accordingly when the files are synced with the origin. It just ignores the file-time of the pushed files.

Doesn't it make sense for the file's modification date to be set to the value of the last commit (remote or local), rather than it leaving it the same as the date it was fetched from the server?

Git stores the last modification time for each file, based on its commit history. Why doesn't Git `touch` each file to their last commit time when the files are pulled from the remote repository?

I know it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1964470/1454514) to modify the config for Git to achieve something like this, but what I'm asking is why Git doesn't set the file time to the time recorded in the commit history *by default*.

If there is a particular reason why Git doesn't do this on default (other than it was a feature that nobody think would be useful), I'm interested to know about the decision against implementing this.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458042/1454514

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's because it would break every build system like `make`, `maven`, `gradle`, etc. that depends on file modification times to know what needs to be rebuilt.  If a `git checkout` or a `git pull` pulls in commits that are older than the last executable you built, it would give those files an older timestamp.  `make` therefore won't detect them as an updated dependency, and won't include those in a new build without doing a `make clean` first.  This is super annoying.

There is `git log` for finding the last time a file was modified in version control and `ls` for finding the last time it was modified on your local disk, and it turns out there's good reasons for keeping those separate.

Comment: That sounds very plausible to me. Still, I'd like to see some quote showing that this was indeed the reason for the original design choice, not just a result of it. Do you have a source?

Comment: @Dan https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, i think its because the goal was to make Git as fast as possible. So instead of adding extra things the focus was (and still is) on making committing and patching as fast as possible.

However i don't think it has ever really been explicitly stated.

Comment: I understand your answer, but as Git *only* modifies the files that are modified on remote, does setting the time after the modification really slow down the process so noticeably to disable such feature?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not completely sure. I'm sure the devs had some reason they came up with when they did it.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft -- "touch" is very fast.  But writing the code to call touch is a potentially-complicated, potentially-buggy extra feature.  When a system (like the earliest versions of Git) is being prototyped, it is important to minimize the number of potentially-buggy features before getting real-world feedback.  And once you start getting real-world feedback, you have effectively created standard interface semantics.  It think it would be impossible to change this interface's semantics in a backward-compatible way.